# Sort array with key as time in format xx:xx

Tags: php

I have this associate array below

```
["12:00" => "Lunch", "07:00" => "Arrival", "07:15" => "Start Tour"]
```

I want to print it in as below ascending by time (key)

```
7:00 => Arrival
7:15 => Start Tour
12:00 => Lunch
```

So far what I've tried is below

```
$arr = ["12:00" => "Lunch", "07:00" => "Arrival", "07:15" => "Start Tour"];

function timecomp($a,$b)
{
    // Subtracting the UNIX timestamps from each other.
    // Returns a negative number if $b is a date before $a,
    // otherwise positive.
    return strtotime($b[0])-strtotime($a[0]);
}
uasort($arr,'timecomp');

print_r($arr);
```

It print this

```
Array
(
    [07:15] => Start Tour
    [07:00] => Arrival
    [12:00] => Lunch
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as your time strings use 24-hour hours and leading zeroes, you can just use `ksort()`:

```
$a = ["12:00" => "Lunch", "07:00" => "Arrival", "07:15" => "Start Tour"];
ksort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [07:00] => Arrival
    [07:15] => Start Tour
    [12:00] => Lunch
)
```